# What is Null doing when it is inserted into an attribute function in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I ran into a strange argument I haven't seen.
In this code, it puts 'null' into attribute and I guess what this null is doing is receive things when 
the function is being chained with others.

**1) I want to ask you guys what the null is doing.** ( where the null is in the code below)

```
var t = svg.selectAll(".symbol").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).attr("transform", null); });

  t.select("path.area")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); });

  t.select("path.line")
      .style("stroke-opacity", function(d, i) { return i < 3 ? 1e-6 : 1; })
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });

  t.select("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { d = d.values[d.values.length - 1]; return "translate(" + (w - 60) + "," + y(d.price / 2 + d.price0) + ")"; });

  setTimeout(streamgraph, duration + delay);
```

**2) I assume,** 
  the variable t is written to avoid repetitive transform argument.
  However, I don't get the order of the argument.
  Because I think, it should be written following this order.

*svg.selectAll('.symbol').select('path.area').attr('d',function(d){return area(d.values);})
.transition().duration(duration).attr('transform','translate(0,0)')....*

However, according to the var t, 
select('path.area') comes after transition and duration and even after .each.

**3) Last question,** 
For the version 4 and 5
.each('end'...) needs to be .on('end'....
right?

Comment: Regarding your second question, the answer is here: https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_select. For the third, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything else, please keep just **one** issue per question here at Stack Overflow.

Regarding the `null`, the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) explains it:

> A null value will remove the specified attribute.

That applies to other methods, such as `style()`.

In this example, the circle has a CSS color ("red"). The D3 code sets another color ("green"), and the `null` reverts to the original CSS color.

```js
const circle = d3.select("circle");
let i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  circle.style("fill", (++i) % 2 ? "green" : null);
}, 1000)
```

```css
circle {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="50" cx="100" cy="75"></circle>
</svg>
```